# Which Windows dll will I find afxwin/CFrameWnd in?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, mfc

I am trying to dynamically load some of the functionality from afxwin but I'm not sure of the name of the DLL I need.

Thanks

EDIT: The class I am looking for specifically is CFrameWnd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon the specific class you are looking for, it can be any of the following dll

MFC42U.DLL (Unicode Release)
MFC42UD.DLL (Unicode Debug)
MFCN42UD.DLL (Unicode Debug - Network classes)
MFCO42UD.DLL (Unicode Debug - OLE classes)
MFCD42UD.DLL (Unicode Debug - Database classe